# htmlencode() for a specific tags only

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a long string dat can contain html tags
applying htmlencode will encode all the tags
but i want this method to leave some specific tags intact
how is it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode the entire string, then decode the specific tags that you don't want encoded.

If you are allowing only simple tags without any attributes (like for example `<b>` and `<u>`), then you can decode them using a simple `Replace`.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming that your input HTML is well-formed,** you can use a regular expression. This is possible because you are not trying to find matching pairs in nested tags, and you are not worried about tags that occur inside HTML comments. Otherwise a regular expression would be a bad candidate for this job.

```
var allowedTags = new[] { "a", "abbr", "br", /* etc. */ };

var output = Regex.Replace(input,
    // Matches a single start or end tag
    @"</?(\w+)[^>]*>",
    // If the tag is one of the allowed tags...
    me => allowedTags.Contains(me.Groups[1].Value)
        // ... keep it unchanged
        ? me.Value
        // otherwise, HTML-encode it
        : HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode(me.Value),
    RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

If your HTML comes from users, then you cannot assume that it is well-formed. In such a case, I would recommend a more robust solution, e.g. using the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).